# How to insert data from one table to other table by other mapping table through procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

There are two tables

```
Table1(Column11, Column12, Column13)
Table2(Column21, Column22)
```

And the following Mapping Table:

```
Table3(Sourcetable,Source column ,Destination table ,Destination column)
```

How to insert data from Table1 as source table and destination table as Table2 , Through Procedures?

I am using oracle 11g; please help to achieve this!

Thanks & Regards,
Hitman

Comment: What have you tried ? Solution is possible using cursors and dynamic sql statements (eg. EXECUTE IMMEDIATE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
DECLARE
sqlstr varchar2(1000);
SourceCol varchar2(1000);
DestCol varchar2(1000);
BEGIN

  FOR aTab IN (SELECT DISTINCT Source_table, Destination_table FROM Table3) LOOP
    FOR aCol IN (SELECT Source_column, Destination_column
                 FROM Table3
                 WHERE Source_table = aTab.Source_table
                 AND Destination_table = aTab.Destination_table)
    LOOP
      SourceCol := SourceCol || aCol.Source_column ||',';
      DestCol := DestCol || aCol.Destination_column ||',';
    END LOOP;
      SourceCol := REGEXP_REPLACE(SourceCol, ',$');
      DestCol := REGEXP_REPLACE(DestCol, ',$');
    sqlstr := 'insert into '||aTab.Destination_table||' ('||DestCol
      ||') SELECT '||SourceCol||' FROM '||aTab.Source_table;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlstr;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

You find Example Schema here [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/762f6/7)

Comment: Hi Wernifried! Can you please help for the new requirement-

Comment: If the requirement is changed to the following then what will be the solution-=?      There are 4 tables:
Table1(Column11, Column12, Column13)
Table2(Column21, Column22)
Table3(Column31, Column32,column33)
Table4(Column21, Column22)

And the following Mapping Table:
Table5(Sourcetable,Source column ,Destination table ,Destination column)
How to insert data from Table1 as source table and destination table as Table2,table3,table,4, Through Procedures?